# Using result from database as a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

My jquery datepicker has the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    var event = ['14 april 2017', '25 april 2017', '1 april 2017'];

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
      inline: true,
      showOtherMonths: true,
      dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
        showpopup();
        getdatespan();
            }
    });


function highlightDays(date) {
      for (var i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
            if (new Date(event[i]).toString() == date.toString()) {
                return [true, 'ui-state-event', ''];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];
    }
...
```

The bit I'd like to focus on is the variable 'event' that is being used to provide dates for the `highlightDays` function. As it is above, the code works perfectly and successfully highlights the date in the variable. However, those dates have been manually typed in by myself.

Below is the code within my calendar.php file:

```
$findEventStartdates = $pdo->prepare('SELECT startdate FROM calendar WHERE username=?'); 

//execute query with variables
$findEventStartdates->execute([$username]);


($eventStartdates = $findEventStartdates->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN));
```

When printed, this shows the following output:

`Array ( [0] => 14 april 2017 [1] => 25 april 2017 [2] => 1 april 2017)`

My question is how can i get whatever is outputted in that PDO to be used as the variable for the datepicker?

In the PHP file i tried the following:

```
$highlightEvents = implode("', '",$eventStartdates);

echo <<<_END
 <input type="text" name="eventHighlight" id="eventHighlight" value="'$highlightEvents'">
_END;
```

This shows:

`'14 april 2017', '25 april 2017', '1 april 2017'`

in the textbox and then tried this with the jquery:

```
var event = [$("#eventHighlight").text];
```

but this did not work. So any alteration to this or different way of using the Array would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Without reading too much into it, for a start, $("#eventHighlight").text should be $("#eventHighlight").text().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on php side to print the array directly into a variable in javascript:

```
var event = <?php echo json_encode($eventStartdates);?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
var event = [$("#eventHighlight").text];
```

By:

```
var event = $("#eventHighlight").text.split(",");
```

Explanation:

`$("#eventHighlight").text` contain a **string**, and your event need an **array**. To do that, you need to **split your string into array** with `split()`.

Comment: afraid this doesn't work. datepicker disappears altogether.